# XCFramework not able to run on rosetta enabled simulator on Apple m1

Tags: ios, swift, apple-m1, xcframework

I have created one custom xcframework in native iOS Swift

Now I have created React Native library project and add my custom xcframework in to iOS folder.

And then I use to do pod install to my example/iOS folder to make it run. I am using Apple M1.

When I run my example/iOS project in real device and apple silicon simulator. It’s working fine.

But when I try to run on rosetta simulator I am getting “Unsupported swift architecture”.

My xcframework structure :

ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator
ios-arm64
Info.plist

I selected rosetta simulator by doing this ( Product - > Destination - > Destination Architecture -> Show Both ). Then I can able to see the rosetta enabled simulators . This error I am getting when I run on  rosetta simulator only

The error :-

- Could not build Objective-C module 'react_native_awesome_module'
- Unsupported Swift architecture

This error I am getting in ios-arm64 slice path header. I am not sure why its taking wrong slice when I try to run on rosetta simulator

Here is my iOS swift xcframework project :

[https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/pint4g7y5sqmv98fd54a5/ShowToast.zip?rlkey=lo30jbtnzdafrrlnsk1or212q&dl=0](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/pint4g7y5sqmv98fd54a5/ShowToast.zip?rlkey=lo30jbtnzdafrrlnsk1or212q&dl=0%E2%80%A8%E2%80%A8)

My react native library project :

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/v55d5oznmvctriq99v605/react-native-awesome-module.zip?rlkey=xlj9h4ocd4pcx96bkmy1uqq5n&dl=0

I have tried added arm64 as excluded architectire on project level, my custom xcframework ( pod level ). my xcframework will be added as pod in the react native library project. but no luck

Comment: Looks like an valid question. why so negative mark without giving any comments.

@arc_react - Try setting up exclude architecture arm64 directly to your pod library alone. keep in note that every time when you do pod install your build setting configuration will get change. so better way is to set via pod and try